# How can I insert a post into wordpress and associate it with a category?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have content from elsewhere that I would like to insert as a post in Wordpress and then associate with an existing category.  It is pretty straightforward to insert a new post into the wp_posts table, but I can't seem to figure out how to construct a query to both insert a new post and at the same time associate the post with a category.  How would one go about doing this?

If it helps, I am using WordPress 2.8

Comment: Do you want to do it with SQL or are WordPress functions acceptable too?

Comment: Edit: Actually, I would prefer SQL so that I can run a script outside of wordpress. Submitted my comment a little too quickly.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this query:

```
INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_title,post_content,post_name,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_author,post_status) 
VALUES ('title','text','post_name',now(),now(),now(),now(),1,'publish')

INSERT INTO wp_term_relationships (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) VALUES ([the_id_of_above_post],1)
```

Comment: Thanks for spelling things out.

Answer (score 5):

Categories are stored in the `wp_terms` tables, with a cross-reference between `wp_posts` and `wp_terms` stored in the `wp_term_relationships table`.

So, you would first need to insert your post into the `wp_posts` table, and then for each of the existing categories that you want to associate it with, insert a record into the `wp_term_relationships` table.

More info here: [WordPress Database Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description)

Answer (score 5):

use the wp_insert_post function then use the wp_set_post_categories function

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference for usage information

Comment: There's also the extended version of the post categories function, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms

That one allows you to set tags, etc as well